# Conditional Copy/Paste in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, conditional-statements, copy-paste

Good evening. Any help that someone can offer on my coding issue will be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to write a macro in JavaScript that copies a sheet and pastes it to another conditionally. I don't want to copy any row's where there is a value of 0 in row 1 (Row A). I wrote a script that removes these rows on the back end but it would be less cumbersome if I can remove the rows prior to the copy. I'm not sure where to add the conditional. Here's what I have so far. (This is between Google Docs).

```
    function CopyConditional() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Copy");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ABCDE").getSheetByName("Paste");
  var targetRangeTop = targetSS.getLastRow(); 
  targetSS.getRange(targetRangeTop+1,1,sourceData.length,sourceData[0].length).setValues(sourceData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
function CopyConditional() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Copy");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ABCDE").getSheetByName("Paste");

  for (var r in sourceData) {
    var row = sourceData[r];
    if (row[0] !== 0) {
      target.appendRow(row);
    }
  }
}
```